# is it possible to print the contents of a div on an A4 using its whole width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to print the contents of a div(a table containing info) using jquery. I was wondering if it's  possible to resize the table in order to use the whole A4s width.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to use a [bleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleed_%28printing%29) to print right up to the edge of the page, or to simply have your navigation and other elements disappear so the width can take up the whole printing area (but still have page margins)?

I don't believe browsers support full bleed printing.

However, if you just want to use the full area with margins, most browsers should auto-size to the largest element on the page.  So, use a [print stylesheet](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/01/10-tips-for-better-print-style-sheets/).

- For testing, Firebug can conveniently show the print view in the browser, or you can simply remove the media="print"
- Hide other elements and make the `div` take up the full width of the viewport
- Make sure to use `width:auto;` on that for best results. Since paper and screen are very different proportions, you don't want the browser mistakenly sizing-down your text because both are defined in pixels and it thinks you want it to preserve proportions.