# Set div size to a4

Tags: css

I am trying to set the size of a div to A4 so that every new box start from a new page. But my box is overlapping over the previous page.

I used this code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446252/stretch-div-to-a4-size) post:

```
.invoice-box {
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 1cm;
    margin: 1cm auto;
    border: 1px #eee solid;
    background: white;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#555;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

but the pages are overlapping.

[image]

How to correct it?

Comment: How about `page-break-after` in CSS?

Comment: thanks it worked ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact fix, but you can set a page break for printing with `page-break-after` definition.