# How can I use CSS to make a div take up an entire A4 page when printing?

Tags: html, css, printing, print-style

I've been messing around with this for hours now and it's driving me nuts. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this should be straightforward:

```
div.A4.page {
          width: 200mm;
          height: 287mm;
          margin: 0;
          border: 5mm solid red;
          padding: 0;
      }
```

An A4 page is 210mm wide and 297mm high. So set to 200mmx287mm with a 5mm border, that should take up the entire page if I do a print preview (set to "print to PDF" with no margins in the print dialog).

However, for some reason it's slightly too small. If I set the border to 10mm, then it seems wide enough but not tall enough.

What's going on here? Am I missing something obvious or is the browser implemenation just bad? (Chromium).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446252/stretch-div-to-a4-size

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the box-sizing property to content-box

```
div.A4.page {
          width: 200mm;
          height: 287mm;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 5mm solid red;
          box-sizing:content-box;
      }
```

**Or**

```
div.A4.page {
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: 5mm solid red;
          box-sizing:border-box;
      }
```

However this may be that your printer options have a set margin by default that you need to remove, most printers leave a margin around the A4 page

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix the problem. And it is not due to the printer margins as I have the margins turned off (it's an option in the Chromium print dialog) and am printing "to pdf". Thanks for your suggestions though.