# How to Make a div fit A4 page

Tags: html, css, django, jinja2

I have a django admin action function that display Transactions and `loops` through as many as queryset selected that will be rendered in html page, and converts the html to pdf.

I want at the pdf that each transaction object fit in A4, not to have another transaction object in same page. here is code..

```
def report_pdf(self, request, queryset):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        transaction = queryset
    else:
        transaction = queryset.filter(user=request.user)
    template_path = "single-pdf.html"
    context = {"transactions": transaction}
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)
    file = open('test.pdf', "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file,
                                encoding='utf-8')
    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    file.close()
    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

and here is my html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Report</title>
<style>

</style>
 </head>
 {% for transaction in transactions %}
 <body>

<div class="container">
    
    {% if transaction.complete %}
    <table class="tg" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-4rlv">Report for Tenant</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-c6of"  CHP Reference</span></td>
                <td class="tg-c6of">{{transaction.chp_reference}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-c6of"> Rent Effective From(dd/mm/yyyy)</td>
                <td class="tg-c6of">{{transaction.rent_effective_date}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-c6of"> CRA Fortnightly Rates valid for 6 months from</td>
                <td class="tg-c6of">{{transaction.cra_rate_from}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-l8qj">Market Rent of the property :</td>
                <td class="tg-c6of">{{transaction.property_market_rent}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-l8qj" >Number of Family Group(s) :</td>
                <td class="tg-c6of">{{transaction.number_of_groups}}</td>
            </tr>
       </div>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stretch div to A4 size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446252/stretch-div-to-a4-size)

Comment: nope, when i add height or width to div it applies to all elements inside it, which i dont want..

Comment: Why do you create <body> for each transaction? put the body element outside the loop, and close the loop